# Wp insert posts при добавлении название поста равно кол-во постов данного типа +1

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть форма где я отправляю заказы на почту + в кастомный тип постов в админке
я хочу чтоб названия постов были такие 1, 2, 3 и т.д.

```
$a = 1; 
$published_posts = wp_count_posts('orders')->publish;
$count = $published_posts + $a;

if(wp_mail($admin_email, 'Заказ с сайта: '.get_bloginfo('name'), $message)) {
    $my_post = array(
            'post_name'     => $count,
            'post_title'    => $count,
            'post_type'     => 'orders',
            'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($message),
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
        );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );?>
```

но в админке они все "1" и слуг у них 1-1, 1-2 и т.д...

Comment: Попробуй написать print_r($published_posts) походу он у тебя ничего не выводит, раз все время равно 0

Comment: да, в functions.php принтером он показывает "1" а в шабе поста - реальное кол-во постов. чего так ?:)

Comment: у меня orders это кастомный тип записей. простые записи он видит а эти нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать хуки, так как когда подгружается файл fucntion.php кастомные типы записей еще не инициализированы.
Вот как должен выглядеть Ваш код:

```
add_action('init','send_order_by_site');
function send_order_by_site(){

    $a = 1; 
    $published_posts = wp_count_posts('orders')->publish;
    $count = $published_posts + $a;

    if(wp_mail($admin_email, 'Заказ с сайта: '.get_bloginfo('name'), $message)) {
        $my_post = array(
                'post_name'     => $count,
                'post_title'    => $count,
                'post_type'     => 'orders',
                'post_content'  => wp_strip_all_tags($message),
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_author'   => 1,
            );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
    }
}
```